# JQuery .on("click", function) not working in iOS

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have the following code. Basically on mobile devices the hover effect gets replaced with a click function. This works fine in the emulator and on android devices. On iOS the on("click", function (e) doesn't work. If l replace the "click" with "touchstart" then the code works perfectly on iOS but stops working in Android.

I have read various solutions to fix the issue like

1. adding "cursor:pointer" in the .css file.
2. I have tried adding the "cursor:pointer" inline via jQuery.
3. I have tried adding a onclick = "void(0)" on the element.

But nothing seems to work. Is there a way to make the Fisher Price OS behave normally?

```
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1366px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.5)").matches) {

    jQuery('.click_and_shop_content a').addClass('noto');    
    jQuery('.click_and_shop_content a').on("click", function (e) {
        
        
        if (jQuery(this).hasClass('noto')) {
            e.preventDefault();

            jQuery('.click_and_shop_content a').addClass('noto');

            jQuery(this).removeClass('noto');
        }
    });
```

Comment: On touch devices, hover is equivalent to a long press. Tapping on the element produces a click event.

Answer (score 1):

After trying to find a more elegant solution that works on both operating systems l used the 'navigator.userAgent' to detect the OS and used the above code with on.("click", for Android and used on.("touchstart", for iOS. All is working as it should now.

```
if( /Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    // Perform actions for Android devices
} else if( /iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    // Perform actions for iOS devices
}
```